# Assigning variable and using it in range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new here and I've just started to use VBA and I will be really grateful if anyone could help me out.

Basically, from cell `A1:D5` were information that I received. These information are periodically add into the spread sheet. `E1:F5` are forumlas which I have already developed in VBA to autofill till the end of `Column A`.

The problem is this, I have over a 100,000 rows of data. So always replaying the macro will require a significant amount of time to process. Is there anyway by which I can write a code that will fill in from the previous rows (i.e. E5 and E6)?

```
    A   B   C   D       E       F
1   6J  6J  HND KMI formula 1   formula 2       
2   6J  6J  HND KMJ formula 1   formula 2       
3   6J  6J  HND NGS formula 1   formula 2       
4   6J  6J  KMI HND formula 1   formula 2       
5   6J  6J  KMJ HND formula 1   formula 2   
6   6J  6J  NGS HND             
7   7A  7A  FUK ISG             
8   7A  7A  FUK KMQ             
9   7A  7A  ISG FUK
```

I have written a simple code to test this out but I was stuck. I think the problem has to do with the declaration of `x` as a variable :

---

```
Sub testloop()

Dim lastrowdatab As String
Dim lastrowpopulate As String
Dim x As String

lastrowdataoriginal = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowformula = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

x = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Address(False, fase)
Range(":J" & lastrowdatab).Formula = "=2+3"

If lastrowdatab <> lastrowpopulate Then

    Range("x:E" & lastrowdataoriginal).Formula = "=2+3"

Else

    MsgBox "all good"

End If

End Sub
```

---

Please help me out! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying (TRIED AND TESTED)?

```
Sub testloop()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LrowA As Long, LRowE As Long, LRowF As Long
    Dim sFormula As String

    '~~> Change this to relevant sheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        LrowA = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LRowE = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        LRowF = .Range("F" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        sFormula = .Range("E" & LRowE).Formula
        .Range("E" & LRowE & ":E" & LrowA).Formula = sFormula

        sFormula = .Range("F" & LRowF).Formula
        .Range("F" & LRowF & ":F" & LrowA).Formula = sFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth,

I forgot to add that one the first row, there would be the respect column titles. This code does not particularly seem to work when the first row names are in place.

Because if that is so, the title would be over written by the formulas. is there anyway to get over it?

Comment: headers should not be a problem. I was under the impression that there will be at least one record in Col E and F. Is that not the case?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Yes that is the case. I was just wondering how the code would look like if i started off with a fresh sheet without any rows except for the titles.