# Assigning variable for a range of colums and using it in range

Tags: excel, vba

[In the given link, code is written for each column because the need is to drag only two columns. Can we select a range of cells to drag whereas i have 30 columns to drag. Will be very helpful if this could be possible. please someone help me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19559652/assigning-variable-and-using-it-in-range/41343847#41343847)

Comment: I cannot imagine a problem that would match this question that would not be answered near the beginning of an Excel VBA tutorial. With `Dim Rng As Range`, either of these: `Set Rng = Range("A1:AD50")` and `Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(50, 30))` set Rng to the same range. `A1:AD50` is a string that can be created at runtime.  `1`, `1`, `50` and `30` could be replaced by variables.

Comment: Hi Tony,I am not clear with the code given, can we edit the same given code to select multiple columns if possible??

Answer (score 0):

If I am unfamiliar with some VBA functionality, I create a little routine like the following and play with that functionality:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()

  Dim Rng As Range
  Dim Rng1 As Range
  Dim Rng2 As Range
  Dim Rng3 As Range

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Set Rng1 = .Range("A1:D5")
    Set Rng2 = .Range("A6:D10")

    Set Rng = Union(Rng1, Rng2)

    Debug.Print "Rng1=" & Rng1.Address & " Rng2=" & Rng2.Address
    Debug.Print " Rng=" & Rng.Address

    Debug.Print "Notice that Union has combined the two ranges because they are contiguous"
    Debug.Print

    Set Rng1 = .Range("A1:D5")
    Set Rng2 = .Range("F1:F6")

    Set Rng = Union(Rng1, Rng2)

    Debug.Print "Rng1=" & Rng1.Address & " Rng2=" & Rng2.Address
    Debug.Print " Rng=" & Rng.Address

    Debug.Print "Notice that Union could not combined these two ranges because they are not contiguous"
    Debug.Print

    Set Rng1 = .Range("A1:D5")
    Set Rng2 = .Columns("B")

    Set Rng = Intersect(Rng1, Rng2)

    Debug.Print "Rng1=" & Rng1.Address & " Rng2=" & Rng2.Address
    Debug.Print " Rng=" & Rng.Address

    Debug.Print "Intersect gives the overlap between two ranges"
    Debug.Print

  End With

End Sub
```

The above macro demonstrates some of the functionality offered by `Union` and `Intersect`.

The key points you need to be aware of:

- A range can be the combination of many non-contiguous sub-ranges.
- Those sub-ranges must all be within a single worksheet.
- I cannot find a definitive maximum for the number of sub-ranges in a range. I have found web pages that give the limit as various values between 2,000 and 4,000. Another claims they have had no problem with move that 4,000 sub-ranges. I assume 2,000 sub-ranges is way above your needs so this is not an issue for you.
- Range.Address is a string with a limit of above 255 characters. More fully it will return as many complete sub-ranges as it can fit within 255 characters.

Try my macro then expand it to better match your requirement.

**Extra section in response to request for more information**

I assumed your concern was with the handling of non-contiguous columns.

In my first comment, I said with `Dim Rng As Range`, the following would set Rng to the say range:

```
Set Rng = Range("A1:AD50")
Set Rng = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(50, 30))
```

Also that A1:AD50 is a string that can be created at runtime and 1, 1, 50 and 30 could be replaced by variables.

You sometimes see statements like:

```
Set Rng = Range("A1:AD" & RowLast)
```

where `RowLast` has been set to the last used row by one of a number of techniques.

I do not believe I have ever used a statement like the above because I prefer:

```
Set Rng = Range(TopLeftCell, BottomRightCell)
```

where `TopLeftCell` and `BottomRightCell` are of the format:

```
Cells(Row, Column)
```

In `Cells(Row, Column)`, `Row` must be an integer or an integer variable. `Column` can be a string ("A", "B", "C", etc.) or an integer (1, 2, 3, etc.) or a string variable or integer variable.  I generally find integer variables the most convenient because I can write:

```
For ColCrnt = 1 To 30 
  Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Value = ??? 
Next
```

In the above I have written `Range` or `Cells` which reference the active worksheet. I almost never need to refer to the active worksheet because most macros work on a specific worksheet which should be referenced explicitly. Referencing the active worksheet means you must rely on the user have the correct worksheet active when they start the macro or you must use the slow `Worksheet.Activate` method.

Better to write something like

```
With Worksheets("Data") 
  RowLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row       ' Last row with a value in column A  
  ColLast = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Row  ' Last column with a value in row 1  
  Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(RowLast, ColLast))
End With
```

Lastly I would add that you will find all this information near the beginning of any online Excel VBA tutorial.  An hour or two looking for a tutorial you like and then working through it will repay itself in time saved very quickly.

Comment: Hi Tony, this code works with the fixed number of cells. but the case is for a variable. it will  be very helpful if we know how to alter this for the variable

Comment: @KarthikaiSelvan  I have added a new section to my answer. Does it help?